# Should I have multiple AFHTTPClients to organize my code

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, afnetworking

We're using AFNetworking to make versioned API requests from our mobile app.

In order to target specific versions of our API, our app sends a special Accept Header.

I've organized my codebase so that each resource (user, session, image, etc.) has it's own AFHTTPClient which sets the Accept header upon initialization.

```
+ (UsersAPIClient *)sharedClient
{
    // removed singleton setup code for brevity
                                                                 // here's where my version gets set for all requests pertaining to Users
    __sharedClient = [[UsersAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url andVersion:2]; 
    return __sharedClient;
}
```

I set it up that way so each request (create user, edit user, get user) wouldn't have to worry about which version to call; that was already done when the specific APIClient was created.

This system is working great but I'm just questioning if this is how I should be doing this? We have about 9 objects, so that's 18 files (.h, .m) on top of the BaseAPIClient class that everything inherits from.

Should all of my networking code just be dropped in one file, and each request sets up the appropriate Accept Header before the request is made? Is there a significant memory overhead by loading 9 different client classes as opposed to just loading 1 giant client class? When designing this system I thought it would be advantageous to only create the APIClients as necessary and on demand. If a user opens the app and never signs in, then I never need to load the code responsible for creating a session. If all of my networking code was stuffed in one file, the first time the user did anything requiring an HTTP request, all networking code would be loaded into memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue would be that your clients and never released after instantiation (the singleton retains a pointer to itself right?). Then you will keep all these objects in memory for the lifetime of your app. Also is may be harder to maintain.

How many versions do you have? Because an easy step to reduce that could be to a client per version and not per object, and the object just call the right version.

What I would do though is to have one file that:

- instantiate a client per version during init
- have methods for the calls that chose the right client so that the objects the call this methods and you centralize the place where you handle the versions.

Also, if it's only setting the request header, maybe you can just have one client and in the calls you set the right header. So that you don't keep multiple clients instantiated.